# Xinerama and double buffering?

Tags: xorg, xinerama

Is there any way to enable double buffering while using Xinerama? Seems its not working because everything is flickering (conky, lilyterm, tilda, ...).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is a limitation of the DBE and double buffering is not possible with Xinerama

There is a discussion here with a link to the source code

http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=110660

I've not found anything more up to date.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that too, but it doesn't help :(

Comment: Well you will need to either code it yourself or file a bug report